# Image upload error using api in android studio in java language . not able to upload image

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to upload image to xampp server, with android-studio and php But I will not succeed Please help me

here is my code(java and php):

java code: in this codes im trying to select picture from gallery and show a dialog and then uploading image...

**signup.java**

```
public class Sign_up extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    
        ApiInterface apiInterface;
        Intent myfileintent;
        Spinner spinner,spinner1;// one for course,and another is indurestry types.
        String filepath=" ";
    
    
        //adding spinner list here.
        String[] Course = {"PHP","WORDPRESS","ANDROID","FLUTEER","PYTHON","DIGITAL MARKETING"};
        String[] I_types = {"15 DAYS","INDUSTRIAL VISIT"};
        EditText R_name,R_email,R_phone,R_password,R_cpassword;
        TextView c_pp,c_ab,c_af,c_mm,c_pay,R_af,R_ab,R_mark,R_payment,R_passphoto;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (requestCode){
    
                case 10:
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                        String path=data.getData().getPath();
                        R_passphoto.setText(path);
                       // uploadImage();
                    }
                    break;
    
                case 20:
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                        String path=data.getData().getPath();
                        R_af.setText(path);
                       // uploadImage();
                    }
                    break;
    
                case 30:
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                        String path =data.getData().getPath();
                        R_ab.setText(path);
                        //uploadImage();
                    }
                    break;
    
                case 40 :
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                        String path =data.getData().getPath();
                        R_mark.setText(path);
                        //uploadImage();
                    }
                    break;
                case 50:
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                        String path =data.getData().getPath();
                        R_payment.setText(path);
                       // uploadImage();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this,"chosse file correctly",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
            }
        }
    
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
            apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    
            //spinner hookup is here.
            spinner=findViewById(R.id.course_spinner);
            spinner1=findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
    
            //all edittext hookup is here..
            R_name=findViewById(R.id.name);
            R_email=findViewById(R.id.email);
            R_phone=findViewById(R.id.phone);
            R_passphoto=findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            R_af=findViewById(R.id.editTex3);
            R_ab=findViewById(R.id.editTex);
            R_mark=findViewById(R.id.editTex2);
            R_payment=findViewById(R.id.editTex4);
            R_password=findViewById(R.id.pwd);
            R_cpassword=findViewById(R.id.cpwd);
    
            //choose file hookup is here
            c_pp=findViewById(R.id.textView);
            c_af=findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            c_ab=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            c_mm=findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            c_pay=findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    
            //adding first spinner list
            ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Course);
            aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            //first spinner working
            spinner.setAdapter(aa);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    
            //adding second spinner list
            ArrayAdapter<String> bb = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, I_types);
            bb.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner1.setAdapter(bb);
            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    
            // all file choose control here..
            c_pp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myfileintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    myfileintent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(myfileintent,10);
                }
            });
            c_af.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myfileintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    myfileintent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(myfileintent,20);
                }
            });
            c_ab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myfileintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    myfileintent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(myfileintent,30);
                }
            });
            c_mm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myfileintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    myfileintent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(myfileintent,40);
                }
            });
            c_pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myfileintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    myfileintent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(myfileintent,50);
                }
            });
    
    
    
        }
    
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id ){
            Spinner spin = (Spinner)parent;
            Spinner spin2 = (Spinner)parent;
            if(spin.getId() == R.id.course_spinner)
            {
    
                Toast.makeText(this, "Your choose :" + Course[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(spin2.getId() == R.id.spinner4)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Your choose :" + I_types[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    
        }
    
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Choose Countries :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    
    
    
        @Override
        public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {
    
        }
    
    //register working model
        public void registeruser(View view)
        {
            Call<responsemodel> responsemodelCall=apiInterface.registeruser(R_name.getText().toString(),R_email.getText().toString(),R_phone.getText().toString(),spinner.getSelectedItem().getClass().toString(),spinner1.getSelectedItem().getClass().toString(),R_password.getText().toString());
            responsemodelCall.enqueue(new Callback<responsemodel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<responsemodel> call, Response<responsemodel> response) {
                    if (response.body()!=null)
                    {
                        responsemodel responsemodel= response.body();
                        Log.i("Response", String.valueOf(responsemodel.isresponse_code()));
                        if(responsemodel.getStatus().equals("success")){
                            SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("credentials",MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                            editor.putString("fname",R_name.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("email",R_email.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("number",R_phone.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("cname",spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            editor.putString("intern",spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            editor.commit();
                            editor.apply();
                            uploadImage();
                            Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this,"user register successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this,"user not register",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<responsemodel> call, Throwable t) {
    
                    Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this,"something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
    
                }
            });
        }
    
        private void uploadImage(){
            File file=new File(filepath);
            File file_ab=new File(filepath);
            File file_m=new File(filepath);
            File file_p=new File(filepath);
            File file_pa=new File(filepath);
            RequestBody requestBody= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
            RequestBody requestBody1= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_ab);
            RequestBody requestBody2= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_m);
            RequestBody requestBody3= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_p);
            RequestBody requestBody4= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_pa);
            MultipartBody.Part part= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename",file.getName(),requestBody);
            MultipartBody.Part part1= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename1",file_ab.getName(),requestBody1);
            MultipartBody.Part part2= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename2",file_m.getName(),requestBody2);
            MultipartBody.Part part3= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename3",file_p.getName(),requestBody3);
            MultipartBody.Part part4= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename4",file_pa.getName(),requestBody4);
            Retrofit retrofit=ApiClient.getApiClient();
            ApiInterface apiInterface=retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<responsemodel> responsemodelCall=apiInterface.uploadimage(R_af.getText().toString(),R_ab.getText().toString(),R_mark.getText().toString(),R_payment.getText().toString(),R_passphoto.getText().toString(),part,part1,part2,part3,part4);
            responsemodelCall.enqueue(new Callback<responsemodel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<responsemodel> call, Response<responsemodel> response) {
                    if (response.body()!=null)
                    {
                        responsemodel responsemodel= response.body();
                        Log.i("Response", String.valueOf(responsemodel.isresponse_code()));
                        if(responsemodel.getStatus().equals("success")){
    
                            SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("credentials",MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                            editor.putString("adharfront",R_af.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("adharback",R_ab.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("mark",R_mark.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("pay",R_payment.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("pass",R_passphoto.getText().toString());
                            editor.commit();
                            editor.apply();
    
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<responsemodel> call, Throwable t) {
    
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**apiinterface.java**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("api/register")
        //agar part nahi work kar raha hai to field change kar dena hai..
        Call<responsemodel> registeruser(@Field("Name") String name, @Field("email") String email, @Field("phone") String phone,
                                         @Field("cname") String cname,
                                         @Field("intern") String intern, @Field("password") String password
        );
    
        @Multipart
        @POST("api/register")
        Call<responsemodel>uploadimage(@Part("adharfront")String adharfront, String part, @Part("adharback")String adharback, String part1, @Part("mark")String mark, MultipartBody.Part part2, @Part("pay") MultipartBody.Part pay, MultipartBody.Part part3, @Part("pass") MultipartBody.Part pass, MultipartBody.Part part4);
```

**responsemodel.java**

```
public class  register{
        private String fname;
        private String pass;
        private String adharfront;
        private String adharback;
        private String mark;
        private String pay;
        private String email;
        private String password;
        private String number;
        private String cname;
        private String intern;
        private String date;

        public String getFname(){
            return fname;
        }

        public void setFname(String fname){
            this.fname=fname;
        }

        public String getPass(){
            return pass;
        }

        public void setPass(String pass){
            this.pass=pass;
        }

        public String getAdharfront(){
            return adharfront;
        }

        public void setAdharfront(String adharfront){
            this.adharfront=adharfront;
        }

        public String getAdharback(){
            return adharback;
        }

        public void setAdharback(String adharback){
            this.adharback=adharback;
        }

        public String getMark(){
            return mark;
        }

        public void setMark(String mark){
            this.mark=mark;
        }

        public String getPay(){
            return pay;
        }

        public void setPay(String pay){
            this.pay=pay;
        }

        public String getEmail(){
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email){
            this.email=email;
        }

        public String getPassword(){
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password){
            this.password=password;
        }

        public String getNumber(){
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(String number){
            this.number=number;
        }

        public String getCname(){
            return cname;
        }

        public void setCname(String cname){
            this.cname=cname;
        }

        public String getIntern(){
            return intern;
        }

        public void setIntern(String intern){
            this.intern=intern;
        }

        public String getDate(){
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date){
            this.date=date;
        }
    }
```

[error in logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hGLm.png)

Comment: `upload image to xampp server, with android-studio` No. With your Android app on your Android device or emulator.

Comment: `String path =data.getData().getPath();` That is no file system path. data.getData() is an Uri. Use the Uri to upload the file. Have a look at data.getData().toString() first and compare with the value of data.getData().getPath().

Comment: `File file=new File(filepath);` Also you should first check if your file exists with `if(!file.exists()) return;` Display also a Toast then to inform the user about the failing 'file'.

Comment: thank you but still error is coming

Comment: Please post the Logcat as text in a new code block. Don't use images. Dont only post a stacktrace but comment on it. And tell which code line causes the error/exception.

Comment: Who is who? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69024446/why-my-image-is-not-upload-in-server-and-alwyas-show-user-not-register