# Why My Image Is Not Upload In Server And Alwyas Show User Not Register

Tags: java, android, api

I'm trying to upload image to server, with android-studio and  But I will not succeed Please help me

here is my code(all code):

java code: in this codes im trying to select picture from gallery and then uploading image

after some time i show in logcat then error show look like image javaclass.exception so please help me to find out the solution for this problem.

```
[error in logcat][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMmwN.png
```

**signup.java**

```
public class Sign_up extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    
        ApiInterface apiInterface;
        Intent myfileintent;
        Spinner spinner,spinner1;// one for course,and another is indurestry types.
        String filepath=" ";
    
    
        //adding spinner list here.
        String[] Course = {"PHP","WORDPRESS","ANDROID","FLUTEER","PYTHON","DIGITAL MARKETING"};
        String[] I_types = {"15 DAYS","INDUSTRIAL VISIT"};
        EditText R_name,R_email,R_phone,R_password,R_cpassword;
        TextView c_pp,c_ab,c_af,c_mm,c_pay,R_af,R_ab,R_mark,R_payment,R_passphoto;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (requestCode){
    
                case 10:
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                        String path=data.getData().getPath();
                        R_passphoto.setText(path);
                       // uploadImage();
                    }
                    break;
    
                case 20:
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                        String path=data.getData().getPath();
                        R_af.setText(path);
                       // uploadImage();
                    }
                    break;
    
                case 30:
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                        String path =data.getData().getPath();
                        R_ab.setText(path);
                        //uploadImage();
                    }
                    break;
    
                case 40 :
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                        String path =data.getData().getPath();
                        R_mark.setText(path);
                        //uploadImage();
                    }
                    break;
                case 50:
                    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                        String path =data.getData().getPath();
                        R_payment.setText(path);
                       // uploadImage();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this,"chosse file correctly",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
            }
        }
    
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
            apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    
            //spinner hookup is here.
            spinner=findViewById(R.id.course_spinner);
            spinner1=findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
    
            //all edittext hookup is here..
            R_name=findViewById(R.id.name);
            R_email=findViewById(R.id.email);
            R_phone=findViewById(R.id.phone);
            R_passphoto=findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            R_af=findViewById(R.id.editTex3);
            R_ab=findViewById(R.id.editTex);
            R_mark=findViewById(R.id.editTex2);
            R_payment=findViewById(R.id.editTex4);
            R_password=findViewById(R.id.pwd);
            R_cpassword=findViewById(R.id.cpwd);
    
            //choose file hookup is here
            c_pp=findViewById(R.id.textView);
            c_af=findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            c_ab=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            c_mm=findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            c_pay=findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    
            //adding first spinner list
            ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Course);
            aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            //first spinner working
            spinner.setAdapter(aa);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    
            //adding second spinner list
            ArrayAdapter<String> bb = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, I_types);
            bb.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner1.setAdapter(bb);
            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    
            // all file choose control here..
            c_pp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myfileintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    myfileintent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(myfileintent,10);
                }
            });
            c_af.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myfileintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    myfileintent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(myfileintent,20);
                }
            });
            c_ab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myfileintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    myfileintent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(myfileintent,30);
                }
            });
            c_mm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myfileintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    myfileintent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(myfileintent,40);
                }
            });
            c_pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myfileintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    myfileintent.setType("*/*");
                    startActivityForResult(myfileintent,50);
                }
            });
    
    
    
        }
    
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id ){
            Spinner spin = (Spinner)parent;
            Spinner spin2 = (Spinner)parent;
            if(spin.getId() == R.id.course_spinner)
            {
    
                Toast.makeText(this, "Your choose :" + Course[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(spin2.getId() == R.id.spinner4)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Your choose :" + I_types[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    
        }
    
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Choose Countries :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    
    
    
        @Override
        public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {
    
        }
    
    //register working model
        public void registeruser(View view)
        {
            Call<responsemodel> responsemodelCall=apiInterface.registeruser(R_name.getText().toString(),R_email.getText().toString(),R_phone.getText().toString(),spinner.getSelectedItem().getClass().toString(),spinner1.getSelectedItem().getClass().toString(),R_password.getText().toString());
            responsemodelCall.enqueue(new Callback<responsemodel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<responsemodel> call, Response<responsemodel> response) {
                    if (response.body()!=null)
                    {
                        responsemodel responsemodel= response.body();
                        Log.i("Response", String.valueOf(responsemodel.isresponse_code()));
                        if(responsemodel.getStatus().equals("success")){
                            SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("credentials",MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                            editor.putString("fname",R_name.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("email",R_email.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("number",R_phone.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("cname",spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            editor.putString("intern",spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            editor.commit();
                            editor.apply();
                            uploadImage();
                            Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this,"user register successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this,"user not register",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<responsemodel> call, Throwable t) {
    
                    Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this,"something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
    
                }
            });
        }
    
        private void uploadImage(){
            File file=new File(filepath);
            File file_ab=new File(filepath);
            File file_m=new File(filepath);
            File file_p=new File(filepath);
            File file_pa=new File(filepath);
            RequestBody requestBody= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
            RequestBody requestBody1= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_ab);
            RequestBody requestBody2= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_m);
            RequestBody requestBody3= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_p);
            RequestBody requestBody4= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_pa);
            MultipartBody.Part part= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename",file.getName(),requestBody);
            MultipartBody.Part part1= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename1",file_ab.getName(),requestBody1);
            MultipartBody.Part part2= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename2",file_m.getName(),requestBody2);
            MultipartBody.Part part3= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename3",file_p.getName(),requestBody3);
            MultipartBody.Part part4= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename4",file_pa.getName(),requestBody4);
            Retrofit retrofit=ApiClient.getApiClient();
            ApiInterface apiInterface=retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<responsemodel> responsemodelCall=apiInterface.uploadimage(R_af.getText().toString(),R_ab.getText().toString(),R_mark.getText().toString(),R_payment.getText().toString(),R_passphoto.getText().toString(),part,part1,part2,part3,part4);
            responsemodelCall.enqueue(new Callback<responsemodel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<responsemodel> call, Response<responsemodel> response) {
                    if (response.body()!=null)
                    {
                        responsemodel responsemodel= response.body();
                        Log.i("Response", String.valueOf(responsemodel.isresponse_code()));
                        if(responsemodel.getStatus().equals("success")){
    
                            SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("credentials",MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                            editor.putString("adharfront",R_af.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("adharback",R_ab.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("mark",R_mark.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("pay",R_payment.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("pass",R_passphoto.getText().toString());
                            editor.commit();
                            editor.apply();
    
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<responsemodel> call, Throwable t) {
    
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**apiinterface.java**

```
   @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("api/register")
        //agar part nahi work kar raha hai to field change kar dena hai..
        Call<responsemodel> registeruser(@Field("Name") String name, @Field("email") String email, @Field("phone") String phone,
                                         @Field("cname") String cname,
                                         @Field("intern") String intern, @Field("password") String password
        );
    
        @Multipart
        @POST("api/register")
        Call<responsemodel>uploadimage(@Part("adharfront")String adharfront, String part, @Part("adharback")String adharback, String part1, @Part("mark")String mark, MultipartBody.Part part2, @Part("pay") MultipartBody.Part pay, MultipartBody.Part part3, @Part("pass") MultipartBody.Part pass, MultipartBody.Part part4);
```

**responsemodel.java**

```
public class  register{
        private String fname;
        private String pass;
        private String adharfront;
        private String adharback;
        private String mark;
        private String pay;
        private String email;
        private String password;
        private String number;
        private String cname;
        private String intern;
        private String date;

        public String getFname(){
            return fname;
        }

        public void setFname(String fname){
            this.fname=fname;
        }

        public String getPass(){
            return pass;
        }

        public void setPass(String pass){
            this.pass=pass;
        }

        public String getAdharfront(){
            return adharfront;
        }

        public void setAdharfront(String adharfront){
            this.adharfront=adharfront;
        }

        public String getAdharback(){
            return adharback;
        }

        public void setAdharback(String adharback){
            this.adharback=adharback;
        }

        public String getMark(){
            return mark;
        }

        public void setMark(String mark){
            this.mark=mark;
        }

        public String getPay(){
            return pay;
        }

        public void setPay(String pay){
            this.pay=pay;
        }

        public String getEmail(){
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email){
            this.email=email;
        }

        public String getPassword(){
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password){
            this.password=password;
        }

        public String getNumber(){
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(String number){
            this.number=number;
        }

        public String getCname(){
            return cname;
        }

        public void setCname(String cname){
            this.cname=cname;
        }

        public String getIntern(){
            return intern;
        }

        public void setIntern(String intern){
            this.intern=intern;
        }

        public String getDate(){
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date){
            this.date=date;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I hve seen this code before a few days ago. With the same errors. Where did you get it from?. The other poster also posted a lot of irrelevant code.

Comment: `String path =data.getData().getPath();` That is no file system path.

Comment: `File file=new File(filepath);
            File file_ab=new File(filepath);` Use File.exists() before upload.

Comment: @blackapps I'm totally beginner in android so please could give proper solution I didn't  get understand your answer.. my question is simple when i try to upload image on server there is not uploading if my all details are correctly upload on server simple toast msg to user successfully register. are the detilas come from api

Comment: here is my api collection for this app [link](https://www.getpostman.com/collections/2bf0aefc210b487b2816)

Comment: Are you @Spark Nikita? The same code. The same errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69011457/image-upload-error-using-api-in-android-studio-in-java-language-not-able-to-up#comment121968100_69011457

Answer (score 0):

Please update below code.

**apiinterface.java**

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/register")
Call<responsemodel>registerWithImages(
        @Part("fname") RequestBody fname,
        @Part("email") RequestBody email,
        @Part("number") RequestBody number,
        @Part("cname") RequestBody cname,
        @Part("intern") RequestBody intern,
        @Part("password") RequestBody password,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part adharfront,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part adharback,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part mark,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part pass
);
```

**signup.java**

```
    private void registerUserWithImage(){
    MediaType text = MediaType.parse("text/plain");

    RequestBody nameBody = RequestBody.create(text, R_name.getText().toString());
    RequestBody emailBody = RequestBody.create(text, R_email.getText().toString());
    RequestBody numberBody = RequestBody.create(text, R_phone.getText().toString());
    RequestBody cnameBody = RequestBody.create(text, spinner.getSelectedItem().getClass().toString());
    RequestBody internBody = RequestBody.create(text, spinner1.getSelectedItem().getClass().toString());
    RequestBody passwordBody = RequestBody.create(text, R_password.getText().toString());

    File file=new File(filepath);
    File file_ab=new File(filepath);
    File file_m=new File(filepath);
    File file_p=new File(filepath);
    File file_pa=new File(filepath);
    RequestBody requestBody= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
    RequestBody requestBody1= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_ab);
    RequestBody requestBody2= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_m);
    RequestBody requestBody3= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_p);
    RequestBody requestBody4= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file_pa);
    MultipartBody.Part part= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("adharfront",file.getName(),requestBody);
    MultipartBody.Part part1= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("adharback",file_ab.getName(),requestBody1);
    MultipartBody.Part part2= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("mark",file_m.getName(),requestBody2);
    MultipartBody.Part part3= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("pay",file_p.getName(),requestBody3);
    MultipartBody.Part part4= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("pass",file_pa.getName(),requestBody4);

    Retrofit retrofit=ApiClient.getApiClient();
    ApiInterface apiInterface=retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<responsemodel> responsemodelCall=apiInterface.registerWithImages(
            nameBody,
            emailBody,
            numberBody,
            cnameBody,
            internBody,
            passwordBody,
            part,
            part1,
            part2,
            part3,
            part4
    );
    responsemodelCall.enqueue(new Callback<responsemodel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<responsemodel> call, Response<responsemodel> response) {
            if (response.body()!=null)
            {
                responsemodel responsemodel= response.body();
                Log.i("Response", String.valueOf(responsemodel.isresponse_code()));
                if(responsemodel.getStatus().equals("success")){

                    SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("credentials",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("adharfront",R_af.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("adharback",R_ab.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("mark",R_mark.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("pay",R_payment.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("pass",R_passphoto.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();
                    editor.apply();

                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<responsemodel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

I hope it works for you!

Comment: hi bro, I follow your code but after so many try I`m not solve my problem after so many try the message will be display user not register.. can you solve my problem to another way.

Comment: hey bro if you don`t mind here is  skype id I will share my code details  and after that if you are find solution than it will be helpful for me and I learn something new so here is my skype id [link]https://join.skype.com/invite/wYWtBCmBzInH